# Join multiple subrepos into one and preserve history in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, subrepos

Currently I have project consisting of multiple repositories, e.g.:

```
+---Project (main repo)
    +---Core (subrepo)
    +---Web (subrepo)
    \---Tests (subrepo)
```

Unfortunately the code between subrepos is quite coupled so it doesn't work nicely with branches.

Is there any way to consolidate the subrepos into one main repository preserving the history?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would start with using `hg convert` with a filemap that excludes the `.hgsub` and the subrepos.  Next, use `hg convert` on the subrepos with rename entries in the filemap like: `rename . Core`

Once you have those new repos, you can use `hg pull -f` to import the changesets from the converted subrepos into the converted main repo one at a time.  You'll also need to merge them into your new main repo (they form separate heads with the null revision as the most recent common ancestor).

Comment: Almost what I wanted. Any ideas on how to preserve the same folder layout?

Comment: @regent: I'd added a comment to yanjost's answer saying how to do this; I've now incorporated it nto my answer.

Comment: Hey I wasn't so far away from the solution ;)

Comment: you can auto-generate this file via the following command chain:
`ls -1 Project | xargs -n 1 echo 'exclude'` (could not edit previous comment because 5 minutes is too long for StackOverflow :-/ )

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/7181613/160799 (original question does the opposite but the rename example in the answer shows our case here) for more details on the pull and merge part.

Answer (score 3):

First guess :
Perhaps by using the [convert extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) with a filemap ?

Another try :

- Pull all your repos into the same repo, you will have different heads for the "default" branch
- Then for each head

  - Update to this head
  - Move the files (hg move) into the right directory
- Merge all the "default" heads together

Edit : added more details, and another try

Comment: It looks like 'convert' even doesn't attempt to convert subrepos when converting the main.

Comment: Force-pulling worked! But any ideas on how to preserve the same directory layout? (Currently the contents of `Core`, `Web` and `Tests` are in the same `Project` folder.)

Comment: @regent: use `hg convert` on the subrepos with `rename` entries in the filemap like: `rename . Core`; then `hg pull -f` from those new repos.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have to convert repos, why not simply push each repo in the central one?

1. Make sure each repo root directory have a main directory named after the repo name.
2. push each repo in the main repo.