# Are there advantages of using hg convert to merge 2 repos instead of hg pull -f?

Tags: mercurial, merge

In the [documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Mercurial) they use a mapfile with these contents:

```
$ echo include subfoo > /tmp/myfilemap
$ echo rename subfoo . >> /tmp/myfilemap
$ hg convert --filemap /tmp/myfilemap /path/to/repo/foo /tmp/mysubfoo-repo
```

What are the advantages of merging 2 repos like. Is there a valid reason not to do this:

```
hg pull -f other_repo
hg merge
```

What are they accomplishing via the rename of subfoo to . ?

Comment: Are the 2 repos related (1 is a clone of the other or both cloned from same repo) or completely unrelated?

Comment: The repos are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Their example (the subfoo filemap you posted in your question) is for converting a subdirectory of an existing repo to a repository of its own, with all the history of the files under that subdirectory. The rename of `subfoo` to `.` means that all files and directories of the directory `subfoo` in the source repo will now be under the root of the new repo.

You could use a filemap with `rename` to do the opposite and to make the contents of the root of repo A now the contents of a subdirectory, then combine it with repo B using `pull`:

```
> echo rename . subfoo > /tmp/myfilemap

> hg convert --filemap /tmp/myfilemap /path/to/repoA /path/to/repoA_converted

> hg -R /path/to/repoB pull -f /path/to/repoA_converted

> hg merge
```

However, [subrepos](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) might be a better alternative to that.

Comment: But, does convert allow you to specify in which folder to pull? If I do a pull+merge, I have to move the files myself if I want them in a different directory.

Comment: Ah, this must be what the rename is for. Right?

Comment: Right. The rename allows you to change the file paths within the repo en-masse, without adding a changeset. In my example, a file `/path/to/repoA/myfile.txt` would end up as `/path/to/repoA_converted/subfoo/myfile.txt`.