# convert mercurial repo with submodules to git repo with submodules keeping history

Tags: git, mercurial, git-submodules, data-conversion

Is there already a tool around which allows to convert a hg repo with hg sub-repos to a git repo with git sub-repos while keeping the sub-repo state history?
It would be nice to know the sub-repo state on each commit.

Comment: Possible solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496047/best-way-to-migrate-mercurial-repo-with-subrepositories-to-git-preserving-histo)